# Question about estimate in proof that $C_c^{\infty}$ is dense in Schwartz space.

Tags: real-analysis, schwartz-space, smooth-functions

I'm reading through [these notes](https://www.staff.science.uu.nl/%7Eban00101/anman2013/anman2013_ch4.pdf), and in particular, the proof of Lemma $4.1.9$ on page 3 of the pdf.

> The space $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is dense in $S(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

They define, [image] and later estimate [image]

I don't understand: How do they obtain the two inequalities for their estimate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking back a few weeks later, I think these are the steps:

\begin{align}
|(\phi_j(x)-1)\partial^{\alpha}f(x)| &=|(\phi_j(x)-1)| \cdot | \partial^{\alpha} f(x)| \\
& \leq (1+\underbrace{\sup |\phi|}_{=1}) \cdot | \partial^{\alpha} f(x)| \\
& \leq (1+\underbrace{\sup |\phi|}_{=1}) \cdot (1+j)^{-1}(1+||x||)|\partial^{\alpha}f(x)| \\ &\phantom{} \text{ the above obtained by noting that $(1+||x||)\cdot(1+j)^{-1} \geq 1$}  \text{ because $||x|| \geq j$
}\\
&\leq 2 \cdot \underbrace{(1+j)^{-1}}_{\leq j^{-1}}(1+||x||)|\partial^{\alpha}f(x)|\\
& \leq 2 j^{-1} (1+||x||)|\partial^{\alpha}f(x)|.
\end{align}